# How to validate zero or more image names, allowing spaces, separated by commas or empty

Tags: php, regex, image, preg-match, filenames

**I need to validate images with regular expressions, with the following conditions:**

1. `$string` may be empty
2. I can receive a single image with this format, for example: `2017-06-01-03-55-00-5930782c5c0b1.jpg`
3. I can get several image names separated by commas example: `2017-06-01-03-55-00-5930782c5c0b1.jpg, 2017-06-01-03-55-00-5930782c5c0b1.jpg`
4. Avoid other special characters other than these: `A-Za-z0-9\-`

I have managed to do this with my knowledge in regular expressions, but I have to validate, if the estring is empty, if there are several images separated by commas, and if there are no other characters than the string.

```
$pattern = '/[a-zA-Z0-9]\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/';
$string = '2017-06-01-03-55-00-5930782c5c0b1.jpg';

if( preg_match($pattern, $string) ) {
    echo "TRUE";
} else {
    echo "FALSE";
}
```

*Thank you very much for your help, please.*

Comment: check `empty()` then `explode()` on commas, then regular expression in array loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do all those things:

`/^(?:[\dA-Za-z-]+\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif))?(?:, (?:[\dA-Za-z-]+\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)))*$/`

It will match the 2nd, 3rd, and 5th line of the following:

```
bad_image.jpg

2017-06-01-03-55-00-5930782c5c0b1.jpg
2017-06-01-03-55-00-5930782c5c0b1.jpeg, bad_image.jpg
2017-06-01-03-55-00-5930782c5c0b1.png, 2017-06-01-03-55-00-5930782c5c0b1.gif
```

Here is the [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/o0PW2M/5).  My pattern will match zero or more valid image filenames which must be separated by `comma-space`

Comment: Hello @mickmackusa, thank you very much for your answer, I have tested the sample code in PHP and it works with empty space, but not functional names of the images, look here: https://eval.in/809859

Comment: This works perfect, thank you very much @mickmackusa.

Comment: This works perfectly in PHP, but I just added this to the Codeigniter Framework, and it shows me the following message: Message: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '/' found, reference documentation: https://codeigniter.com//user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#rule-reference

Comment: @Learningandsharing You can just swap back in the lowercase characters then...  `/^(?:[\dA-Za-z-]+\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif))?(?:, (?:[\dA-Za-z-]+\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)))*$/`

Comment: Your example works fine in PHP, but in Codeigniter it shows me the following message: Message: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '/' found

Comment: @Learningandsharing Hmm, curious.  please post your code.

Comment: @Learningandsharing How about this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21439805/codeigniters-regex-match

Comment: Perfect, I will use this method, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for the following, since your regex pattern didn't account for the dashes.

```
/[a-z0-9-]+\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)/gi
```

A great resource for perfecting your regex can be found at [Regexr.com](http://regexr.com)

The /g at the end of the expression makes the pattern global, looking at the whole string passed to it rather than finding the first match and stopping.

The /i at the end of the expression means case insensitive so that you don't have to include both a-z and A-Z.

Comment: Hello Eddy, I need to know if the string is empty, if there is a comma, or more than one filename.

Comment: Ahhh... sorry, I missed that part. 
It's been too long since I've worked with PHP, so I can't help you out with that part.

Comment: Actually.. check this out.  Found it here on StackOverflow.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007777/php-regex-how-to-get-an-array-of-matches

Comment: Hi Eddy Jones, @mickmackusa's response is very good, let's see her.